# What is y axis in seaborn distplot figure?

Tags: seaborn

i'm using the following statement to plot a distribution fig:

```
a = sns.distplot(df, norm_hist=True)
```

[image]

and there is no difference when I change the norm_hist to false.
how can i interpret the y axis, it seems not count nor probability.

Comment: @DizietAsahi You marked as duplicate, yet gave an answer below. Which one is it? Would it make sense to give the answer at the linked question instead?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I thought there were two questions in one here. But when I started answering the bigger question, I realized others can probably answer much better than I ever could, hence the duplicate flag. Feel free to mark as duplicate, since the answers there are more complete.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference when `norm_hist=False` because you are also plotting the KDE, which implies that `norm_hist=True`, if you want to see the non-normalized histogram you have to call

```
a = sns.distplot(df, norm_hist=False, kde=False)
```

When you are only showing the histogram (`kde=False`) and you don't normalize (`norm_hist=False`), then the y-axis represents the count in each bin.

Comment: thanks, but why the y axis is > 1, i guess it would be a probability and less than 1 if it's kde, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: that's a common misconception, refer to the above duplicate question for better explanations

Comment: thanks, it should be that the area under the curve be 1